# Lighttpd wont restart due to an fastcgi.server error

Tags: php, lighttpd, fastcgi, php5

Here is what comes up when I try to restart lighttpd

```
user:/# /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
Stopping web server: lighttpd.
Starting web server: lighttpdDuplicate config variable in conditional 0 global: fastcgi.server
2010-02-13 22:08:30: (configfile.c.907) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 179 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL) 
failed!
```

Lighttpd restarts fine when I comment out fastcgi config lines.

Comment: apt-get had already installed the php config stuff into the lighttpd enabled folder there for I didn't ned to re-write it into the lighttpd.conf file. Thought i'd mention that for anyone else who gets the same error one day (solved) (will go into it in better detail latter and answer my own question when I have more time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, my fault turned out to be that php was already configured with lighttpd with the config file already being placed into the conf-eneabled folder:

```
/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-fastcgi.conf
```

Just deleting my own fastcgi code inside of /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf fixed my issue, hope it helps anyone else who have the same issue.